# "Unsupported database scheme" from apt-get during reinstall

Tags: fedora, troubleshooting, apt-get

I am receiving the following error from `apt-get`. What could cause this and how can I correct it?

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall aptitude
Reading Package Lists... Error!
E: opening /var/lib/apt/lists/download.fedoraproject.org_pub_fedora_linux_development_rawhide_x86%5f64_os_repodata_2053842c8e82d7226232844c73801c08e55bd4e9971402388a02b3038f06cf84-primary.sqlite.xz db failed
E: Unsupported database scheme (0)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 0):

While someone has packaged apt-get into the Fedora package collection, this is not an officially supported tool for installing packages. If that's what you're trying to do, please use `dnf`.

A new version of apt for RPM hasn't been released since [2008](http://apt-rpm.org/). If you're really interested in making apt work on Fedora, you might want to get involved with that project.

Comment: ok there is no other method to add this Packages ?, cause in terminal a line asked me if i should forced installation and i did write yes and the problem start from that moment ?? i'm not professional i need for something clear to do ? and thank you for your comment

Comment: What is the end goal you are trying to accomplish? Apt and aptitude are tools for adding and removing packages on Debian-based distributions, which does not include Fedora. On Fedora, we have an equivalent but different program called `dnf`. Read more about it at http://dnf.readthedocs.org/. Or, if your goal is to install end-user applications, you may prefer to simply use GNOME Software -- press the Window key on your system and type "software" and look for the programs you want there.